# delayed_jobs not creating rows in delayed_jobs table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

In may rails application i wanted to use delayed job. SO i installed delayed jobs as follows.

in gemfile

```
 gem 'delayed_job_active_record', '0.4.3'
```

then in console

```
 rails generate delayed_job:active_record

 rake db:create
```

It had created delayed_jobs table in database.

And i started

```
 rake jobs:work
```

Then i added the following code in controller:

```
 Task.handle_asynchronously :in_the_future, :run_at => Proc.new { 5.minutes.from_now }
```

here Task is the model name.

And in the model task.rb i wrote

```
 def in_the_future
   self.update_attiributes(:status=> "updated")
 end
```

After running controller method  it's not creating any record in the delayed_jobs table. Please correct me if i am doing anything wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can You change the controller code to

```
Task.delay(:run_at => Proc.new { 5.minutes.from_now }).in_the_future
```

Comment: how to pass parameters to in_the_future method?

Comment: You can also pass the parameters with in_the_future and you must specify that in model